# XML creation using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I'm using this code in Codeigniter to generate XML:

```
public function get_cuisine()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $sql = "select * from cuisine";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $config = array (
        'root'    => 'root',
        'element' => 'element',
        'newline' => "\n",
        'tab'     => "\t"
    );
    echo $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);   
}
```

But this shows the general print format. How can I get it to show as an XML type page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to set XML headers if you want to output the file directly:

Using the Codeigniter [Output class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html):

```
$xml = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
$this->output->set_output($xml);
```

Or you can use plain PHP to set the [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
```

Or you can use the CI [download helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html):

```
$xml = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('myfile.xml', $xml);
```

Or write it to a file with the [file helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html):

```
$xml = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
$this->load->helper('file');
$file_name = '/path/to/myfile.xml';
write_file($file_name, $xml);
// Optionally redirect to the file you (hopefully) just created
redirect($file_name);
```

Comment: Could you please little elaborate about the  $file_name = '/path/to/myfile.xml'; my file path is  $file_name = base_url('application/controllers/test.xml'); I guess the problem is into $file_name.

Comment: @Shiplu use the full server path to the file, not your website's URL.

Answer (score 2):

I had also the same question. I have googled it. Found this solution. And it works perfectly for me.
[Click here to get the source code](https://github.com/accent-interactive/xml_writer)

Just download and unzip ( extract it)

Then copy the **xml_writer.php** in application->libraries of the extracted folder  to your libraries folder in your Codeigniter project.

Also copy the **xml.php** in the application->controller in to your controllers folder

Finally copy the **xml.php** in the views of the extracted folder in to your view and run it..

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

Custom solution:

```
$mysql_data = $this->db->get('products')
                    ->result_array();
$xml = '<root>';
foreach($mysql_data as $row){
  $xml .= '<item>
             <name>'.$row['title'].'</name>
             <price>'.$row['price'].'</price>
             <image>'.$row['pic'].'</image>
           </item>';
}
$xml .= '</root>';
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
$this->output->set_output($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter 4 it's much easier. You can use the integrated response object and just do something like:

```php
return $this->response->setXML($xmlString);
```

This simplifies it a lot, in my case I generate the XML using views and then just output the XML using this same thing, just something like:

```php
return $this->response->setXML(view('myfeed'));
```