# XML Page view from Codeigniter

Tags: xml, codeigniter, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML creation using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361074/xml-creation-using-codeigniter)

```
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
echo $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config)
```

From above code I can't see the data set in XML format. In my view page it shows the the data in the normal view as I saw it before.

Comment: I posted an edit to my answer on your other (same) question that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this

```
function user_get()
{
    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

        function users($id){

            $query = $this->db->get('student');
                    $this->db->where('EID', $id); 
            $config = array (
                              'root'    => 'users',
                              'element' => 'item',
                              'newline' => "\n",
                              'tab'    => "\t"
                            );
            $this->load->dbutil();
            echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> ';
            print $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
        } 

    $id = @$users[$this->get('id')];

    if($user)
    {
        $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
    }

}
```