# One line messes up XML with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, xml, codeigniter

From this code I get exactly what I want in xml but it doesn't work in the browser because there is an empty line in front

```
function Users_get(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $data['rows'] = $this->User_model->getUsers();

    $f = 1;
    foreach ($data['rows'] as $r):
        $users[$f] = array(
            'user_id' => $r->ID, 
            'Destination' => $r->Destination);
        $f++;
    endforeach;

    $this->response($users, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
}
```

The result in xml:

```
LINE 1 :EMPTY LINE MESSING UP THE ENTIRE OUTPUT
LINE 2 :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LINE 3 :<xml><item><user_id>1</user_id><Destination>Valencia</Destination></item>...
```

Because of the empty line I get error:

> "This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error."

JSON outputs ok....

my view

```
 <body>

      <a href="<?php echo site_url('userAPI/user/user_id/1');?>">Specific user</a>
      <br>

      <a href="<?php echo site_url('userAPI/alluser');?>">All users</a>
      <!-- <p>FlightFrom: <?php //returnJasonName('2');?></p> -->
      <br>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('userAPI/Users_get/user_id/1');?>">user from database</a>
      <br>


      <?php  foreach ($rows as $r):?>
           <p><?php echo $r->ID;?></p>
           <div><?php echo $r->Destination; ?></div>

     <?php endforeach; ?>

 </body>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter but I'd say that's code from the controller. Isn't that blank line inserted in the view?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10361155/496176

Comment: Show code for your view.

Comment: Mike, i am an complete noob when it comes to codeignator but my view is not in any way involved in this as far as i can tell.. how ever i will put it up cause i am a beginer.. $this->response($users, 200); is in my belif what generates the output?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a CodeIgniter expert, and so I can't really help you identify the problem.

However, a quick and dirty solution would be to use **[`trim()`](http://php.net/trim)** on the output.