# Make URL Suffix optional in codeigniter with .php and without .php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My project is almost complete so I cannot make changes in url throughout project.whenever I use redirect like

```
redirect('welcome?loggedout=true', 'refresh');
```

Page get redirected to

```
welcome?loggedout=true.php
```

I have added URL suffix

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.php';
```

But can I use it as optional and url remains normal with extension until I want to customise a link with .php.

Comment: After all the research,i found that there is only one way to achieve this.
Use route for pages where you want extension and leave url_suffix empty.

Comment: you should make $config['url_suffix'] = ''; or try it using simple php redirect header("Location: http://example.com/welcome.php?loggedout=true");

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: @Lupin - I m asking how to make URL suffix optional.

Comment: when will you use it and when not?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Query String URL’s, edit `config.php` which is located in  `application/config`.  Set ***`enable_query_strings`*** to `TRUE` and define controller and function trigger.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

**Output**

[image]

[Go through this source](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=enabling%20query%20strings#enabling-query-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement and update, you can use suffixes for some URLs only and not all your project - using routes from codeigniter. OP mentions this on his comment but provided no examples.

Here's a example:
http://antsplace.co.uk/url-suffix-in-codeigniter/

I did not do the same thing. In my case, I just needed suffixes for .xml pages
So I only put, on routes.php :

```
$route['newsfeeds/(:any)\.xml'] = 'newsfeeds/index/$1';
```

And created a Newsfeeds controller and index function to handle. That's it. That way only URLs with /newsfeeds on segment 1 will allways apply/accept .xml suffix

index controller function is likely many others:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('xml');
        $this->load->view('xml_view');
    }
```

Don't forget to call `header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");` in your site header to properly render xml to this views or you can do this with codeigniter inbuilt function as described in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361155/2387741

And at last this xml helper (docs [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/xml_helper.html)) help you translate some characters that need correct formatting on xml to work properly.

I guess this is it. Best regards.